# Is $C^{\infty}(M) \subseteq L^2(M, \text{loc})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. Is it true that every smooth function on $M$ is also in $L^2(M, \text{loc})$? If so, could you give me some hint as to how to prove it or suggest a reference where I could find a proof? I tried to show that for any coordinate patch $U$ and any smooth $f$ we have $f|_U \in L^2(U)$, but I couldn't justify this.

Answer (score 1):

$C(M)$ functions are locally bounded. Remember that manifolds are locally compact, and compact sets have finite measure.

What you tried to show is not true: you could take $M={\bf R}$ and $f=(x\mapsto x^2)\in C^\infty(M)$. $M$ is a single coordinate patch and $f=f\vert_M$ is not integrable in any way.

Comment: So you can choose a coordinate patch $U$ and $W \subset K \subset U$ where $W$ is open and $K$ is compact. Then $\int_W f|_W dV \leq \int_K f|_K dV < \infty$ as $f|_K$ is continuous and $K$ is compact. So $f|_W \in L^2(W)$, so $f \in L^2(M, \text{loc})$. Is this correct?

Comment: @user121031: I don't think you need to refer to the manifold structure at all: it's an abstract fact that continuous functions are locally bounded (on any space whatsoever), and therefore they are locally integrable with respect to any locally finite measure. Manifold structure is only important as far as defining the actual measure and noticing that it is locally finite (which it is, because it is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on coordinate patches, with continuous $\implies$ locally finite derivative).

Comment: @user121031: but yeah, that's mostly correct, except you might comment that $W$ was chosen as a neighbourhood of an arbitrary point before the last point follows.